# How should I understand "She cracked open a door"?

Tags: verbs, meaning-in-context, prepositions

I learned the following sentence from *100 Greatest Science Discoveries of All Time* by Kendall Haven:

> Marie Curie's studies rank as one of the great turning points of science. Physics after Curie was completely different than before and focused on the undiscovered subatomic world. **She cracked open a door that penetrated inside the atom and has led to most of the greatest advances of twentieth-century physics.**

I don't understand the sentence in bold. Why can two verbs, "cracked" and "open", be put together in this sentence? Or do I misunderstand the part of the speech here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's **not** two verbs, *cracked* and *open*. It's one phrasal verb, *crack open*. *Open* is the particle (open can be an adjective and an adverb, as well as a verb), and *crack* is the verb.

To *crack* means to make a crack, or opening, in something, which can be literal, like *crack an egg*, or figurative, like *crack the books* (which means *study*) or *crack another bottle of scotch*, which means to open a sealed bottle.

The phrasal verb *crack open* means to open something sealed (like a door) a very small amount ("only a crack"), so that one can see inside. It refers to the very **beginning** of an opening.

In this case, it's metaphoric, and refers to the first "opening" of scientific knowledge of the atom, which was due to Curie's work.

Comment: I think it means that she forced the door open rather than "opened the door a little bit".  Cracking open a bottle or cracking a safe doesn't mean "open up a crack" it means force the thing wide open.  Likewise *cracking an egg* is to break it.  It's clear from the context that the author believes the work was a momentous, even violent act of scientific discovery.

Comment: @z7sg Ѫ: I don't think so. I'd hazard a guess that almost every one of [14500 instances of "cracked the door open"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22cracked+the+door+open%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) are in a *stealthy, inquisitive* context. Whereas it's possible the *stealthy* connotation is irrelevant in OP's example, I think John is on the money with both the *inquisitive, so one can see inside*, and *first opening* connotations. I don't really see safe-cracking as an important reference here (but a bottle of fine cognac, maybe! :)

Comment: Yes, you crack open a door (open it just a little bit) to sneak a peek, or have a secret listen to what's going on on the other side of the dorr.

Comment: Hmm, is "cracked open a door" the same as "cracked a door open"? That may be more understandable.

Comment: Yes. It's a phrasal verb, so Particle Shift is optional with noun objects and obligatory with pronoun objects (i.e, _*He cracked open it_ is ungrammatical).

Comment: Ah, yes. Before I read the context - "Marie Curie" - I was thinking "Barbarian Princess with large axe."

Comment: @Jack. I must say that *cracked a door open* would give me pause. I'd understand it, but I'd find *cracked open a door* far more idiomatic.

Comment: @TRIG: Marie Curie would tell you that the **open** particle can jump to the end of the phrase. It's a natural phenomenon. It's no less idiomatic.  I actually find it more idiomatic. And with that, he slammed the door shut.

Comment: You'd *break open a door* or *break down a door* if you were doing it violently.

Comment: Or you could **blow the house in**. https://youtu.be/Olo923T2HQ4